# Changing dropdown direction of Meteor Accounts

Tags: angularjs, meteor

I'm using the Meteor packages:

```
 accounts-ui
 accounts-password
 accounts-facebook
```

And I've implemented the Meteor accounts in my view like the following:

```
<meteor-include src="loginButtons"></meteor-include>
```

Right now, the 'Sign-In' link is aligned to the right so I want it to dropdown to the left, but it is dropping on the right, hence, its not fitting in the browser. [image]

[![1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y707i.png)]

I want to change it so it drops to the left, thus, it will be on the page. Also, I'm using AngularJS w/Meteor

Answer (score 1):

If inside a regular `.html` file, it is easy to do that to use spacebars syntax like:

```
{{> loginButtons align="left"}}
```

If inside a `.ng.html` file, it is advisable to follow the api from [angular-meteor](http://angular-meteor.com/api/blaze-template): using `blaze-template`.

1. `meteor add urigo:angular-blaze-template`
2. In your main `.html` file, create a new Blaze template: 

   `<template name="loginButtonsWithParameters">
     {{> loginButtons align="left"}}
   </template>`
3. In your `.ng.html` file where you want to include loginButtons, add:
   `<blaze-template name="loginButtonsWithParameters"></blaze-template>`

Comment: Not using spacebars. Using Angular

Comment: Is your code inside a `.html` file ? If so, it makes no difference to use `{{> }}` compared with `<meteor-include>` as spacebars are allowed.

Comment: Its a ng.html file. I just tried what you suggested and it didn't work

Comment: I find `blaze-template` api in the official website of angular-meteor. Try my new edit.